# Redis subscribe in julia script not working

Tags: redis, julia, publish-subscribe

I'm using Julia v0.4.5 and have this simple julia script to subscribe from redis channel:

```
using Redis

subHandler(x) = print(x)
errHandler(err) = print(err)

redisConn = RedisConnection(host="127.0.0.1", port=6379, db=0)
flushall(redisConn)

subConn = open_subscription(redisConn, errHandler)
subscribe(subConn, "julia-channel", subHandler)
```

If I type this script line by line in Julia repl, it works as expected.
  However, if I put this code into a script file and run from shell:

```
julia sub.jl
```

Julia exits with nothing printed in a few seconds..
  Maybe I should put the subscription into some kind of thread or loop (to keep julia running)?

Comment: println(subscribe(subConn, "julia-channel", subHandler))?

Comment: I would guess that @FGFW is on the right track. You're probably just seeing the output of the last line when running in REPL (which is equivalent to calling `display` on the last line). If you want the script to be interactive, you will need to add that to your script!

Comment: @FGFW println(subscribe(subConn, "julia-channel", subHandler)) prints '47' on terimal and julia still exits.

Comment: @DanielArndt In repl, the last line doesn't print anything. When there's data published on the subscribed channel, **subHandler** (not subscribe()) prints subscribed data. According to redis.jl readme, subscribe() "spawns a routine that runs in the background to process events received from the server". Thus I guess the background routine should keep julia running, but that's not true...

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Julia definitely won't keep itself alive for background tasks, this has caused some strange "pipe closed" issues for me in the past, particularly in tests when I try printing things.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by FGFW and DanielArndt, I just found the answer.
In short, after subscribe(), adding the following code to keep julia run:

```
while (true)
  sleep(1)
end
```

Explanation:
According to redis.jl readme, subscribe() spawns a background routine to handle server publish events. However, in script mode, julia main thread(routine) exits after subscribe(), so that background routine is also terminated. The while - sleep loop prevents main loop from exiting.
Repl maintains user interactive loop, so we don't have to loop by hand.